Javascript Event Source Error: {isTrusted: true} when connecting to Mercure
I have Angular on Front - End,
I have a very weird issue:
I am connecting to a Mercure - server events with EventSource in Javascript.
In case of an error for example when I simulate wrong authorization or whatever, the only thing that I receive via browser is:
{isTrusted: true}
I have red this blog: https://blog.sentry.io/what-is-script-error/
And according to the blog and other sources the issue is caused by Browser it is a Script Error.
But I tried catching the error in try catch blog,
I setup the headers according to that article.
This is how the error is handled.
How I can get some normal error format?
    this.eventSource.onerror = (error: ErrorEvent): void => {
      console.log(error);
      if (attempts === 0) {
        this._logger
          .sendToRemote$({
            id: traceId,
            log_level: 'ERROR',
            log_message: `Mercure connection dropped, after ${EVENT_SOURCE_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS} failed attempts`,
            BODY: JSON.stringify({ message: error.message, fileName: error.filename, lineNumber: error.lineno }),
            STEP: 'ERROR',
            traceId,
            context_data: {
              sessionUid
            }
          })
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe();
      }

      if (attempts > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.startEventSource(attempts - 1);
        }, 2000);
      }
      throw error;
    };


that link says it's because it's a cross-origin request. The remote server has to allow your origin so that the browser can get the error response... (as is it's showing you part of the request body... "isTrusted" is a property of the event... true there basically means it was user-initiated, so maybe that's from a user allowing notifications?) but you probably don't need the error.  This is almost certainly a network error. (server connection problem)

The blog suggests wild-carding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", but you should know that CORS rules won't allow wildcard origins when sending credentials.  (It's not clear if the initial connection to EventSource requires authorization.)

You can see the basic algorithm here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#the-eventsource-interface

Thank you very much, It makes sense I will try to specify the origin instead of wildcard :)
